# Declare function with space inside a typings file

Tags: types, typescript-typings, .d.ts

Is there a format to declare a function with space in its name inside a `.d.ts` file?

Something in the form of:

```
export namespace Foo {
    function "foo bar"(): void;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a function declaration with a space directly. You could use `namespace-class` merging to achieve what you want:

```
export class Foo {
  private constructor() { } // so nobody acidentaly instantiates this
  static ["foo-bar"] = function (): void {

  }
}

export namespace Foo {
  export function other() {

  }
}

Foo.other() // ok
Foo["foo-bar"]() // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=4&pln=12&pc=5#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAEBjANgQwM6cQMWtIgN7CKKSwCWAbuvKCtAHabywCuy8cAFAJTFEAX0QB6UYkyEm0AEbQAJgE9E6ZJQWgm8dKhWUWO7ZTqgc8ABaVMpSTviVkiANoAiAGYEAtLPSxXALqIALyI7uxMXJTMiPwAXIjU0BrEtmS2QsCZYFBwSEzoALZmkGoM+IQkZBAwCGERUTHQlqCw-Klk6WSZ2RUAdM0Wre3iiNAA1sAVbp7QPn6BIxITiEA)

Note: Avoid namespaces in new code, use modules instead.

Comment: What's the difference between namespaces and modules?

Comment: `namespaces` are an old TS construct for code separation. Modules (not to be confused with the `module` keyword in ts) are the standard ES2015 way to organize code

Comment: Thanks, I assume the proper syntax for a `.d.ts` file is: `static ["foo bar"]: () => void;`?